# Best xcode project type to practise objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a simple console type project where I can hack objective-c and test things out, and simply output to a console?

I want to practise things like class defining, instances, looping, arrays, dictionaries etc.

Answer (score 10):

If you require Xcode, File -> New Project… -> Mac OS X/Application -> Command Line Tool/Foundation.

If you’d like not to use Xcode, this is what I do: use favourite text editor and type

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main() {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // whatever code you want to test
    NSLog(@"hello, world!");

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

compile on a shell (e.g. using Terminal.app) with

```
clang yourSourceFileName.m -o executableName -framework Foundation
```

or

```
gcc yourSourceFileName.m -o executableName -framework Foundation
```

and then run

```
./executableName
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure. From the `New Project` dialog, choose `Application` under the Mac OS X heading, then `Command Line Tool`.  A drop-down selection will allow you to choose a particular type of project, which defaults to `C++ stdc++`.  Simply change this to `Foundation` and you will have a template ready to start exploring all the non-Cocoa (UI) frameworks.

From here you can create instances of `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSDate`, and many other useful non-GUI classes.  See the full list here:

- [Foundation Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001091)

Comment: My guess is that he’d want Foundation instead of Core Foundation.

Comment: Yes, good point - if he wants to learn the ObjC-style classes instead of the C-based interfaces in CF. I've updated the text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

In Xcode, under New Project, choose Application --> Command Line Tool

This will let you play with objective-C classes and output to console, without the clutter of a full blown cocoa GUI application.

Comment: Should include the type as well.